# How to parse a number as either an int or a float, depending on required precision?

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting

Requirements:

1. Input can be either string or number
2. If input could be treated as an int without loss of precision, cast to int
3. If input could be treated as a float, cast to float

Here is the section of code where I am using this.

```
def make_operand(symbol, left=None, right=None):
    valid_symbols = ['*', '/', '+', '-']
    if symbol in valid_symbols:
        return Operand(symbol, left, right)

    as_int = re.compile("^-?[0-9]+$").match(str(symbol))
    as_float = re.compile("^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$").match(str(symbol))

    as_number = int(symbol) if as_int else float(symbol) if as_float else None

    if as_number:
        return NumericOperand(as_number)

    raise ValueError("Invalid symbol or number")
```

This works but it looks messy and smells wrong.

An implementation using try blocks also works, but seems less simple:

```
    as_number = None
    try:
        as_float = float(symbol)
    except ValueError:
        as_float = None

    if as_float:
        as_int = int(as_float)
        as_number = as_int if as_int == as_float else as_float

    if as_number:
        return NumericOperand(as_number)

    raise ValueError("Invalid symbol or number")
```

Is there a better approach, or is one of these close to the Pythonic method of doing things?

Comment: Very close to your `try-except` block: `try: as_number = int(symbol) except ValueError: as_number = float(symbol)`

Comment: @zondo that creates a chained exception though if `float` also fails.

Comment: You probably want to change `if as_float` to `if as_float is not None` because when `symbol = 0` it will not work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind third party modules, there is a C-exension module called [fastnumbers](https://pypi.org/project/fastnumbers) that was designed exactly for this purpose. The [fast_real](http://fastnumbers.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#fastnumbers.fast_real) function does exactly what you are looking for (provided you use `coerce=True`, available on `fastnumbers>=0.7.4`).

Full disclosure, I am the author.

```
>>> from fastnumbers import fast_real
>>> fast_real('56')
56
>>> fast_real('56.0')
56
>>> fast_real('56.07')
56.07
>>> fast_real('56.07 lb')
'56.07 lb'
>>> fast_real(56.07)
56.07
>>> fast_real(56.0)
56.0
>>> fast_real(56.0, coerce=True)
56
>>> fast_real(56)
56
>>> fast_real('56.07 lb', raise_on_invalid=True) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '56.07 lb'
```

Comment: I have a question about your module and have created a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106822/inquiry-about-fastnumbers)

Comment: I like the performance, and will probably use this in another project. However, it won't work in this case as I need to prefer ints over floats and fastnumbers seems to convert everything to a float.

Comment: I see. The behavior is to return the input as-is if it is already and int or float to about object creation overhead.

Comment: @BrianHVB I imagine if there were a `coerce` option that would coerce a float to int this would work for you?

Comment: @BrianHVB I made an update to [fastnumbers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fastnumbers) (version 0.7.4) that includes a ``coerce`` option to ``fast_real`` to coerce to ``int`` when possible.  Please investigate if this works for you.

Comment: Seems like it will do the trick and the interface is cleaner than what I have. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

since [PEP 367](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0357/) any python object that can be cast to an integer without precision loss will define a `__index__` method so that it can be used in indices.  The only special case is with a `str` so you can do:

```
def as_num(value):
    if isinstance(value,str):
        try:
            return int(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass #don't put return float(value) here or you will get chained exceptions
        return float(value) #this might fail and raise the error
    elif hasattr(value,"__index__"):
        return value.__index__() #possibly just int(value) if the method exists?
    else:
        return float(value) #this would fail if the object cannot be cast to a float
```

Although it is possible this won't pick up on special cases where `__index__` is not defined but `int` and `float` return equivalent values, in which case the code you already have is almost fine.  Just change `if as_float` to `if as_float is not None` so that `symbol=0` doesn't fail and you're good to go, although the structure can be simplfied a bit:

```
try:
    as_float = float(symbol)
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError("Invalid symbol or number") #maybe just let the other error go instead?
else:
    if as_float.is_integer():
        return NumericOperand(int(as_float))
    return NumericOperand(as_float)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about PEP 367. Never thought to __index__ as a way to check for int-ness.

Comment: @BrianHVB interesting trivia: `bin` and `hex` were only intended to use true integers so they in fact use `__index__` for custom objects passed to them. this way `hex(numpy.int16(5))` works correctly while `hex(2.0)` raises an error.